# Formulario con más de un botón para ejecutar otras acciones

Tags: html

Al hacer *click* en el botón de un formulario se ejecuta el archivo **php** que está en el *action*.

```
<form method="post" action="crear.php" >
( ... )
<input type="submit" value="Crear
```

Necesito otro botón en el formulario para ejecutar otro archivo **php**.
Cuál es la mejor manera de hacer esto de forma segura que revele las carpetas del sistema?

Comment: ¿Quieres esconder el nombre del segundo archivo PHP? Es decir, ¿que nadie pueda averiguar el nombre mirando el HTML?

Comment: Bueno, primero quiero poder tener otro botón que ejecute otro archivo php. Y si es posible ocultar la ruta de dicho archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con:

```
<input type="submit" onclick = "this.form.action = 'pagina1.php' />
<input type="submit" onclick = "this.form.action = 'pagina2.php' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te recomendaría de hacer es de enviar el `submit` a un solo archivo PHP, donde después filtras para realizar la tarea en cuestión. De esta forma tendrás mucha flexibilidad, ya que podrás enviar las solicitudes de otros formularios o requests al mismo archivo.

Por ejemplo:

**index.html**

```
<form action="router.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Crear en el sistema" name="crear">
    <input type="submit" value="Eliminar del sistema" name="borrar">
</form>
```

**router.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['crear'])) {
    // Haz algo para crear
}

if (isset($_POST['borrar'])) {
    // Haz algo para borrar
}

?>
```

Si vas a tener muchos botones entonces utiliza un [switch()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php).

Ocultar la ruta del archivo PHP no es posible ya que lo tienes que poner en `action`, pero no te tendría que preocupar. Si filtras bien entonces al visitar el archivo directamente no te podrán hacer nada ni ver el código fuente.

Comment: Una consulta. Y no es necesario utilizar __<input type="hidden">__ para mayor seguridad?

Comment: `<input type="hidden">` es para esconder un campo, **no te dará mayor seguridad**. Generalmente se utiliza para añadir campos con valores predeterminados donde no hace falta que lo vea el usuario, como podría ser la ID de la página donde están rellenando el formulario. Aún así cualquier persona mirando el código fuente de la página (el HTML) podrá ver el valor.